# Page fully loaded event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run 2 functions that animate some images after the page is completely loaded (I'm using Jquery Circulate Plugin). I tried `$(document).ready(function` but the images are not showing at all on the first loading, they appear only after refreshing the page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".zenn").each(function() {
            $(this).circulate({
                speed: Math.floor(Math.random()*300) + 100,
                height: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470,
                width: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) - 470
            });
        });

    $(".zenn").css("left", $(".zenn").position().left).circulate({
            loop: true,
            width: 0,
            height: 10
        });
    });
```

Link to the web page : http://ngit.ma/jgr/

I will be grateful for any help or suggestion since I'm new to Javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [$(window).load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of $(document). ready()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(window).load(function()
  ...
})
```

$(document).ready doesn't wait for images.  $(document).load does! :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer is to use:

```
$(window).load(fn);
```

It will fire after all the resources including images are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // do your logic here..  
});
```

`$(document).ready(fn)` is triggered as soon as the DOM is ready, but `$(window).load(fn)` will wait for all the resources to load before it is triggered.